# Change Password for Azure AD using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I was planning to use Azure AD Graph API but then noticed on the Microsoft docs about suggestions to use Microsoft Graph API.

Is there a documentation provided for changing a user's password?

```
string result = Task.Run(async() => { return await GetAccessToken(); }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        (requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }));

var changePasswordRequest = graphserviceClient.Me.ChangePassword("oldpassword", "newpassword");
```

However I don't think this is sufficient. Any documentation available?

Answer (score 4):

You could update `passwordProfile` property to change the current user's password . Please refer to below code :

```
await graphClient.Me.Request().UpdateAsync(new User
{
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        Password = "YourPassword",
            ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false
    },
});
```

And according to [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update), one of the following scopes is required to execute this API: `User.ReadWrite` `User.ReadWrite.All` `Directory.ReadWrite.All`.

**Edit:**
The [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update) has been updated with the following note:

> When updating the `passwordProfile` property, the following scope is required: `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.

Comment: I've personally found that I was unable to reset passwords even with all those granted. Only by making the service principal a Company Admin did it get permissions to reset passwords. The documentation was wrong at that time at least.

Comment: AFAIK, only Azure Active Directory Premium or Basic could make a user(not admin) reset password himself , otherwise only admin could reset user's password in a free version .

Comment: When updating the `passwordProfile` property you the delegated  `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` scope is required. It allows an Admin to change another user's password.

Answer (score 1):

See here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/10/17/unable-to-modify-user-email-phone-number-password-or-other-personal-information-for-azure-active-directory-users/

If you call this from an app/api, you'll need to assign an AD role to the serviceprincipal of the application.