# Microsoft Graph Api-Change Password

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I have created Users in Azure AD and with the help of Microsoft graph api trying to change the password of users but getting error message as admin rights required.
Help is appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to change the password of other users? or your signed in user?

Comment: I am trying for both to change the password of other users as well as for my signed in user

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625460/change-password-for-azure-ad-using-microsoft-graph/43626003

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Password for Azure AD using Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625460/change-password-for-azure-ad-using-microsoft-graph)

Answer (score 5):

```html
   {
   "passwordProfile": {
                "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
                "password": "newPassword"
            }
    }
```

Try doing a patch and changed the attribute. This also worked for me in the past.

Comment: This totally works with Graph API (if your permissions are sufficient).  Why no upvotes for you?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which api you are using , Azure AD Graph API or Microsoft Graph api . But no mater which api , the change password operation is used for the signed-in user to change their own password :

microsoft graph api :

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/changePassword
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "currentPassword": "Test1234!",
  "newPassword": "Test5678!"
}
```

Azure AD Graph api :

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/me/changePassword?api-version=1.6
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "currentPassword": "138122cC@",
  "newPassword": "138122c@"
}
```

Please refer to document : https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/functions-and-actions#changePassword

> > Note: This action can only be called on the signed-in user. In addition to addressing the operation by using the me alias as shown below, you can use /users//changePassword or /users/userPrincipalName/changePassword, but if you use these addressing modes, the target user must be the signed-in user.

If target user isn't the signed-in user , it will throw error :`Access to change password operation is denied.`

Comment: Thanks for that link - the documentation on the changePassword endpoint is buried deep!

Comment: I do not think the Microsoft Graph API code snippet is correct, don't think you can do what you are suggesting with the Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: @mattruma ，the reply is in 2017 , two years may change everything . i haven't confirm that  nowadays .

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct, at least now.  If your application's Graph API permissions are sufficient you can totally do this today, using the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ endpoint and the patch suggested by Acrhaf C. below.

Comment: @user12861 can you elaborate on your experience? Because it does not work for me in 2021.

Answer (score 2):

the user who create the application, or user in the application, must assign as "user administrator" in role setting.

Comment: Ok, howto add user administrator in role setting ?

Comment: the solution is here https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/programming/9781838551230/2/ch02lvl1sec25/assigning-the-user-administrator-admin-role-in-azure-ad

Answer (score 0):

In order to change password you need to give your application the role of "Help Desk Administrator" which has to be done through windows powershell .

These are the sequence of commands to be typed in Windows Power shell to give your app the role of Help Desk administrator.

1. `Install-Module MSOnline`
2. `Install-Module AzureAD`
3. `Connect-MsolService` (after this you will be prompted to login , the user logged in should be a global administrator)
4. `Connect-AzureAD` (after this you will be prompted to login , the user logged in should be a global administrator)
5. `$tenantID= "yourtenantid"`
6. `$appID = "your app id"`
7. `$myAp = Get-MsolServicePrincipal -AppPrincipalId $appID -TenantID $tenantID`
8. `$objectId = $myAp.ObjectId`
9. `Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleName "Helpdesk Administrator" -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal`

-  `RoleMemberObjectId $objectId`

After doing all these steps then if you do

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/changePassword
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "currentPassword": "Test1234!",
  "newPassword": "Test5678!"
}
```

then the password will be successfully updated !