# User Update in MS Graph not working while Read works

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Microsoft Graph API to access my Azure B2C Tenant.

Here is my code:

```
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(_azureB2CSettings.Value.TenantId,
        _azureB2CSettings.Value.AppId.ToString(), _azureB2CSettings.Value.ClientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        var user = await graphClient.Users[azureVetOsId.ToString()].Request().GetAsync();
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new AzureB2CUserNotFound(azureVetOsId.ToString());
        }
        
        user.PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile()
        {
            Password = newPassword,
            ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
        };

        await graphClient.Users[azureVetOsId.ToString()].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
```

The get operation works perfectly, I get the user and can see all data. I even created the user seconds before with Graph API without problems.
Now, the UpdateAsync Requests get's an

```
 Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

I checked the persmissions of the app registration within azure:
[image]

That seems fine, the User.ReadWrite.All is set correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can update user password like this. You can either reset password, or user can update his password if he knows the old one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-changepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: What do you mean, how I can update it then?

Comment: Hmm, it seems I was wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625460/change-password-for-azure-ad-using-microsoft-graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:
Additional to the delegated rights, you need to be an User Administrator as a Role with the app / user you are using here:

[image]

Additional to that the code should never send a loaded object in the update, just the property you want to update:

```
            await graphClient.Users[azureVetOsId.ToString()].Request().UpdateAsync(new User()
        {
            PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile()
            {
                Password = newPassword,
            }
        });
```

Comment: Version 5 of the Graph SDK supports a backing store where you can request an object, make changes and send an update with the same object and only the changes will be send: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#backing-store